# How to show a header in Jquery pop up window?

Tags: jquery

I have two questions here.

1. How can I show the header of the pop up window?
2. How to show the radio buttons to the user in the pop up window.

Currently I am doing as mentioned in the below.

```
$.prompt( "WARNING: Selected:'"+ $('[id$=Office]').val()+
           "' has both values, Please choose one.",
      {
    buttons: {                  
         'Small': 1,
         'Large': 2
     },
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with $.prompt... Is prompt the same as jqueryui dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might better off just switching it to a [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). You'll get all the features you're asking for out of that.